# MVC Kendo Grid read.Action().Data(function) not called on a forced datasource.read()

Tags: jquery, telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Our code has two dropdowns.  When the `onchange()` for the first fires it calls `$("#classDropDown").data("kendoDropDownList").dataSource.read();` to force the second one to update.

```
<%: Html.Kendo().DropDownList().Name("speciesDropDown")
          .DataTextField("Text")
          .DataValueField("Value")
          .DataSource(source =>
          {
              source.Read(read =>
              {
                  read.Action("GetNLSSpecies", "RefData").Data("noFilters");
              });
          })
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 50%" })
          .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
%>
...
<%: Html.Kendo().DropDownList().Name("classDropDown")
          .DataTextField("Text")
          .DataValueField("Value")
          .DataSource(source =>
          {
              source.Read(read =>
              {
                  read.Action("GetClassData", "RefData").Data("mergeData()"); 
              });
          })
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 50%" })
          .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
%>
```

Elsewhere ...

```
$('#speciesDropDown').on('change', function (event) {
    ...
    $("#classDropDown").data("kendoDropDownList").dataSource.read();
}
```

The `mergeData()` function is called to provide data from the Javascript to the server.  The **problem** is that because I'm calling this as a function it is **NOT** called during the `dataSource.read()`.  But it is called initially when the page first loads.

Obviously I could change this to `mergeData` (ie. not a function) but it is the simplest case.  I'm actually trying to pass arguments, something like:

```
    .Data("mergeData('getSpeciesDropdownObj','getShownOrRequired(\"OtherClass\")')")
```

This seems like a bug to me.  Does it to you?

I wanted to post this at the https://www.telerik.com/forums/ but it is only open to the license holders and I currently don't have access to the details.  I'm hoping Telerik monitor this and can give me some feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look how the Razor markup get transalated and your

`Data("mergeData('getSpeciesDropdownObj','getShownOrRequired(\"OtherClass\")')")`

will get translated into

`data : mergeData('getSpeciesDropdownObj','getShownOrRequired(\"OtherClass\")')")`

Since `transport.read.data` could containt both Object or Function this may lead to confusion.

In your case `transport.read.data` won't contain a reference to a function but a reference to an object (the result of the function evaluation).While `Data("mergeData")` will set `transport.read.data` to a reference of mergeData function.

If you need to specify some additional parameter I suggest you explore the other `Data` overload.

In that case this would be your starting point:

```
Data(@<text>function mergeData(){}</text>)
```

Otherwhise you could define a closure for `mergeData`.

Eg.

```
Data("mergeDataHelper")

function mergeDataHelper(){
   return mergeData(); //add your custom parameters here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Your explanation sounds plausible (except JS can easily distinguish between different types). Though why does it work the first time?  I did end up using the closure method you described though this is not scalable.  MergeData() takes n objects args and combines the result in to one.  Theoretically I want to have "an infinite" number of possible arguments.

Comment: Scalable -> `mergeData_getSpeciesDropdownObj_getShownOrRequired_OtherClass` is the method to replace what I wrote about!

Comment: Because mergadata is evaluated while the drop down list is rendered. Probably since the code is executed to the point where getclassdata is called by Ajax your application state doesn't change so you find yourself within the correct values.

Comment: Do you mean that it is evaluated only initially?  But a non-function is evaluated every time (I confirmed by printing the date).  I find it confusing and I'm going to pursue discussing this with Telerik.  Thank you @Giovanni for your attempts to help me understand this.  I'll write back to here with any thing I learn.

Answer (score 0):

It is working as expected, but need some tweaks on it
**Kendo MVC Grid:**

```
.Read(read => read.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { area = "AreaName" }).Data(@<text>function filterCustomJavaScriptFunction(){
return {
Param1: $("#Param1").val(), 
Param2: $("#Param2").val(),    
timeTick: new Date().getTime()
};
}</text>))
```